# Find occurrence using multiple attributes in ElementTree/Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="10" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0.001" name="AllTests">
  <testsuite name="TestOne" tests="5" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0.001">
    <testcase name="DefaultConstructor" status="run" time="0" classname="TestOne" />
    <testcase name="DefaultDestructor" status="run" time="0" classname="TestOne" />
    <testcase name="VHDL_EMIT_Passthrough" status="run" time="0" classname="TestOne" />
    <testcase name="VHDL_BUILD_Passthrough" status="run" time="0" classname="TestOne" />
    <testcase name="VHDL_SIMULATE_Passthrough" status="run" time="0.001" classname="TestOne" />
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Q : How can I find the node `<testcase name="VHDL_BUILD_Passthrough" status="run" time="0" classname="TestOne" />`? I find the function `tree.find()`, but the parameter to this function seems element name.

I need to find the node based on attribute : `name = "VHDL_BUILD_Passthrough" AND classname="TestOne"`.

Comment: Your `testsuite` tag is not closed?

Comment: @eumiro : it was a typo, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This depends on what version you're using. If you have ElementTree 1.3+ (including in Python 2.7 standard library) you can use a basic xpath expression, as [described in the docs](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm), like `[@attrib='value']`:

```
x = ElmentTree(file='testdata.xml')
cases = x.findall(".//testcase[@name='VHDL_BUILD_Passthrough'][@classname='TestOne']")
```

Unfortunately if you're using an earlier version of ElementTree (1.2, included in standard library for python 2.5 and 2.6) you can't use that convenience and need to filter yourself.

```
x = ElmentTree(file='testdata.xml')
allcases = x12.findall(".//testcase")
cases = [c for c in allcases if c.get('classname') == 'TestOne' and c.get('name') == 'VHDL_BUILD_Passthrough']
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate through the `<testcase />` elements that you have, like so:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET

# assume xmlstr contains the xml string as above
# (after being fixed and validated)
testsuites = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
testsuite = testsuites.find('testsuite')
for testcase in testsuite.findall('testcase'):
    if testcase.get('name') == 'VHDL_BUILD_Passthrough':
        # do what you will with `testcase`, now it is the element
        # with the sought-after attribute
        print repr(testcase)
```